# VoIP dialer for SIP

Tags: database, opensource-projects, asterisk, voip, sip

I have some Java, so am biased in that direction, but not overly so.  None of the Java suggestions:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16471795/sip-client-for-java
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498043/what-is-the-currently-popular-java-sip-library

jump out as fantastic solution.  What's "the" best FOSS dialer? By "best" I mean simplest to deploy.

The requirement is preview dialing:

> Preview dialing enables agents to first view the available information
>   about the customer and decide when to place the call. In addition to
>   the information about the customer, agents may also view all the
>   history of the customer with the contact center. After viewing the
>   information about the customer, the agent requests the system to make
>   the call.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialer#Preview

Currently, hard phones connect with SIP to a hosted Asterisk PBX. The goal is to replace the hard phones with soft phones, such as [zoiper](http://www.zoiper.com/en/tutorials/ldap), **and** speed up the dialing process.

[ViciBox](http://www.vicibox.com/server/) looks very interesting, but would, apparently, create a bottleneck with the hosted PBX and is overkill.  If I could deploy just the dialer and interface, but use the hosted Asterisk PBX, that would be good.  However, it would probably be a bit complex to install.

I'm looking for a quick and dirty solution. Down the road, it will probably be ViciBox, but the easiest and quickest to install and configure would be best.

Of all the FOSS dialers, which one can be installed stand-alone easiest, and has a strong community?

I suppose it's technically possible to checkout the [code for ViciDial](http://wiki.vicidial.org/index.php/SVN:howto), but that's more involved than I would like.

Optimally, I would like a FOSS dialer, with a queue, which pops a record from the database, sends it to an agent, the agent dials, edits the file, and updates the record.  That's exactly what ViciBox does, except, in this case, Asterisk isn't required.

Comment: I dunno how on target this is for you, but I imagine something like [`sipML5`](http://sipml5.org/) should be pretty easily customizable. Deploying that kind of thing seems like it might be as easy as installing a web browser...

Comment: Here is their [technical guide](http://webrtc2sip.org/technical-guide-1.0.pdf).

Comment: that's pretty slick.  My only concern is performance, handling VoIP.

Comment: I'm not really certain how it would work - which is a big reason why this is a comment and not an answer - as I'm just an outsider looking in. But I did notice this in the tech docs: *If your provider or hosted server
supports SIP over WebSocket (e.g. **Asterisk** or **Kamailio**) then, you can bypass the module and
connect the client directly to the endpoint.*

Comment: I'm not sure if this fits the dialer requirement, but VoiP performance-wise Linphone works very well.